# How to find strings that have words starting with particular set of letters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have managed to make it work when I have to pick single word strings that start from particular letter. However, I was not able to get it to work when the string has multiple words and we had to compare starting letter of both.

Suppose, there is list containing strings as below:

```
mylist = ["hello world", "hello", "how well", "how world is", "he is great"]
```

I would like to pick out the strings that have first word starting with "**h**" and second word starting with "**w**".

So output I was expecting from above list was filtering out "**hello world**" and "**how well**"
I would like to filter out words that do not contain exactly two words as well.

Below is the code I had till now which checks only first letter of the words:

```
for word in mylist:
    if word[0]==letter:
        print(word)
```

I tried several variations of *startswith*, but have not found a way to compare multiple words in a string yet.

Comment: Since you managed to solve it for a single word, what remains is the task to split a sentence into single words. Search for that and you'll find plenty of solutions.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't want: `"he might wait"` — you're just interested in the first two words?

Comment: Yeah that was correct. @MarkMeyer

Comment: looks like homework, solution would not be useful for developers

Comment: @sanyi  it was not any homework. But I get what u mean. In that way, yes all I was looking for was a working solution, as I was just using it as a cron function which has to scan daily files for my personal project, and was not not worried about the most effective piece of code currently, as long as it does what it is intended to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for word in mylist:
    try:
        if word.split()[0].startswith('h') and word.split()[1].startswith('w'):
            print(word)
    except:
        pass
```

The `split()` splits the word by space. This lets us the access to each word, from which you can check. Here and is used since both conditions should be satisfied.
Also for strings with two words:

```
for word in mylist:
    try:
        if word.split()[0].startswith('h') and word.split()[1].startswith('w') and len(word.split())==2:
            print(word)
    except:
        pass
```

Here is a one-liner for you:

```
[word for word in mylist if len(word.split())==2 and word.split()[0].startswith('h') and word.split()[1].startswith('w')]
```

Without a one-liner:

```
for word in mylist:
    if len(word.split())==2 and word.split()[0].startswith('h') and word.split()[1].startswith('w') :
        print(word)
```

Comment: It worked as intended Joshua, thanks. However, as stated in question, I might just need to ensure it filters out strings which has more than 2 words. Like a string "how well is" should not be considered as string which starts with "h" and "w". I believe we would need to add another condition to check the count of it ?

Comment: ya sure. add a len of for the split. i'll add the code

Comment: @Sriram add that too try now

Comment: @Sriram since you are sure you only need two worde strings. you can avoid the try except

Comment: That serves the purpose and works as intended. Accepting the answer, thank you !

Comment: @Sriram sure. Welcome to SO

Comment: @Sriram Looks like you unticked the answer. Maybe you pressed the tick two times

Comment: Sorry, did not realize it ! Accepted.

Comment: @Sriram no prob :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
my_list = ["hello world", "hello", "how well", "how world is", "he is great"]

for phrase in my_list:
    words = phrase.split()
    try:
        if words[0].upper().startswith("H") and words[1].upper().startswith("W") and len(words) == 2:
            print(phrase)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

You have to use try and except to because if the phrase has fewer than 2 items it will throw an IndexError.

Comment: That works and serves the purpose, thank you.

Comment: if you put that len() first, you dont require the try - except

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Brilliance runs in the name!

Answer (score 2):

A little recursion allows you to check each word against each prefix.

```py
mylist = ["hello world", "hello", "how well", "how world is", "he is great"]
prefixes = ['h', 'w']

def filter_prefix(string_list, prefix_list):
    def recursive_startswith(words, prefix):
        if not prefix:
            return True

        if words and words[0].startswith(prefix[0]):
            words.pop(0)
            prefix.pop(0)

            return recursive_startswith(words, prefix)

        return False

    return [x for x in string_list if recursive_startswith(x.split(), list(prefix_list))]

print(filter_prefix(mylist, prefixes))
```

This will also let you match against any number of prefixes you desire.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom function for your requirements and pass it into the filter builtin function in python.

```
def find_word(string):
    mystring = string.split()
    return (mystring[0].startswith('h') and mystring[1].startswith('w')
            if len(mystring) > 1 else False)


mylist = ["hello world", "hello", "how well", "how world is", "he is great"]

output = list(filter(find_word, mylist))  # filter your list
# ["hello world", "how well", "how world is"]
```